# Java Swing dependencies from multiple actionable objects

Tags: java, swing, listener

What is the proper way to program (in Java Swing) the dependencies from/between multiple actionable objects?

E.g. let's say we have 2 JButton objects and 2 other GUI objects (e.g. 2 JLabel objects)
When JButton1 is clicked, JLabel1 should become visible and alter its text to "NewText1", while JLabel2 should become invisible.
When JButton2 is clicked, JLabel1 should become invisible, while JLabel2 should become visible and alter its text to "NewText2".

I came up with a couple solutions, none of which I like myself 
(mostly based on sub-classing JLabel objects to ensure that have different ActionPerformed methods, then registering them as listeners with JButtons).
But this does not scale at all since for every dependent/listener object (in this case JLabel), I end up creating a new class.
With the proliferation of GUI objects, all these classes quickly become difficult to track and manage. On the other hand, I would prefer to avoid the use of anonymous classes since I may need access to those GUI elements from other pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

> When JButton1 is clicked, JLabel1 should become visible and alter its text to "NewText1", while JLabel2 should become invisible. When JButton2 is clicked, JLabel1 should become invisible, while JLabel2 should become visible and alter its text to "NewText2".

I enabled the text, rather than made it visible or invisible.  This way, the text didn't shift in the JPanel.

[image: Two Action Listeners]

I wrote two action listeners, one for each of the buttons.

If you have six JButtons and six JLabels, you'll have to write six action listeners.  You would write an action listener for each JButton.

I would have made the action listeners anonymous classes, but since you said you didn't want that, I made them separate inner classes.

Here's the code that produced the GUI.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TwoActionListeners implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Two Action Listeners");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 30, 5));

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.addActionListener(new Button1ActionListener());
        mainPanel.add(button1);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button2.addActionListener(new Button2ActionListener());
        mainPanel.add(button2);

        label1 = new JLabel("New Text 1");
        mainPanel.add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel("New Text 2");
        mainPanel.add(label2);

        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TwoActionListeners());
    }

    public class Button1ActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            label1.setEnabled(true);
            label2.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    public class Button2ActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            label1.setEnabled(false);
            label2.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}
```